# Iterate through a Vector in java

Tags: java, renjin

I am retrieving values from an R script (using the Renjin library) and then trying to manipulate them in java. The R script returns a ListVector which looks like:

```
c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L...10 elements total)
c(0.70836348202446, 3.27419352963856, 4.08477502998281, 4.11959291310495, 4.64797692435211,... 10 elements total)
c(10.88276411602949, 11.01414766445697, 14.22416580313999, 14.40880862158516, 15.64782262321588,... 10 elements total)
```

I want to be able to get specific elements from each Vector so in the first experiment I would like to be able to iterate through so I can print out all the elements.

To do this I am doing

```
ListVector exp = (ListVector) engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("/Users/sebastianzeki/Desktop/script.R"));
        java.util.Iterator<SEXP> itr = exp.iterator();
        System.out.println("Iterating through Vector elements...");     

                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    java.util.Vector<SEXP> v=new Vector<SEXP>();
                    v.add(itr.next());
                    java.util.Iterator<SEXP> itr2 = v.iterator();

                    while(itr2.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println("My Elements"+itr2.next());
                                         }
                                    }
```

However this just prints out each of the Vectors separately so that i end up with

```
    My Elementsc(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L...10 elements total)
    My Elementsc(0.70836348202446, 3.27419352963856, 4.08477502998281, 4.11959291310495, 4.64797692435211,... 10 elements total)
    My Elementsc(10.88276411602949, 11.01414766445697, 14.22416580313999, 14.40880862158516, 15.64782262321588,... 10 elements total)
```

Comment: What library are you using? What type is `engine`, `ListVector`, `Vector`?

Comment: It looks like you have one vector containing three elements, each of which is itself a vector.  You are iterating over those three elements.  If you want to iterate over the elements of those three vectors, you need a second loop inside the first one.

Comment: And what is `SEXP`? That's essentially what you're printing out here.

Comment: I am using the Renjin library to call R

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "toString()" which provides debugging output but generally doesn't print the entire contents of the vector.

You access the individual elements of the vectors by calling `getElementAsObject(i)` or the typed accessors `getElementAsDouble(i)`:

```
for(SEXP element in exp) {
  Vector elementVector = (Vector)element; // if you're sure this will be a vector
  for(int i=0;i<elementVector.length();++i) {
     System.out.println("[" + i + "] = " + elementVector.getElementAsDouble(i));
  }
}
```

You can find more documentation on this API on [docs.renjin.org](http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/renjin-java-api-specification.html#org-renjin-sexp)